# how to make the clock tick by pressing the start button

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

How to make the clock tick by pressing the start button. If i press START several times, the time will be updated, but I need only press once to update the clock every second. It's unclear why the recursive function call does not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>


  <input type="button" onclick="clock.clockStart()" value="Start">

  <input type="button" onclick="clock.clockStop()" value="Stop">

  <div class='clocks'>
    <span class='hours'></span>
    <span class='minutes'></span>
    <span class='seconds'></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    'use strict';

    class Clock {
      constructor() {
        this.hh = document.querySelector('.hours');
        this.mm = document.querySelector('.minutes');
        this.ss = document.querySelector('.seconds');
      }


      clockStart() {
        let self = this;

        self.date = new Date();

        self.timer = setTimeout(function tick1() {

          self.hh.textContent = '' + self.date.getHours();
          self.mm.textContent = ': ' + self.date.getMinutes();
          self.ss.textContent = ': ' + self.date.getSeconds();

          self.timer = setTimeout(tick1, 1000);
        }, 1000);
      }
      clockStop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
      }

    }

    let clock = new Clock();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: well date is always the same.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you set `self.date = new Date();` That is the time stamp at that point in time. It is not going to keep updating.

So if you want the time to change, you would need to move it inside of your timer and declare it on every iteration.

```
self.timer = setTimeout(function tick1() {
    self.date = new Date();
    /* rest of your code */
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes and added comments to explain why I've made the changes. I hope this makes it clear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>


  <input type="button" onclick="clock.clockStart()" value="Start">

  <input type="button" onclick="clock.clockStop()" value="Stop">

  <div class='clocks'>
    <span class='hours'></span>
    <span class='minutes'></span>
    <span class='seconds'></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    'use strict';

    class Clock {
      constructor() {
        this.hh = document.querySelector('.hours');
        this.mm = document.querySelector('.minutes');
        this.ss = document.querySelector('.seconds');
      }


      clockStart() {
        // There is no need for self. You're using ES6 and thus you have fat 
        // arrow methods that keep the this reference the same.

        // Use setInterval instead of useTimeout, you want this to be called 
        // every second. In addition, using a fat arrow function will make sure 
        // this still refers your instance of the Clock class.
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
          // You need to refresh date each time before showing it in your UI.
          this.date = new Date();
          this.hh.textContent = '' + this.date.getHours();
          this.mm.textContent = ': ' + this.date.getMinutes();
          this.ss.textContent = ': ' + this.date.getSeconds();

        }, 1000);
      }
      clockStop() {
        // When stop is clicked, cancel the interval.
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }

    }

    let clock = new Clock();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Recursive setTimeout is a more flexible method of timing than setInterval, since the time until the next execution can be scheduled in different ways, depending on the results of the current one. Thank you too.

Comment: For example, we have a service that polls the server every 5 seconds for new data. In case the server is overloaded, you can increase the polling interval to 10, 20, 60 seconds ... And then return back when everything is normalized.

If we regularly pass the tasks that load the processor, then we can estimate the time spent for their execution, and plan the next launch sooner or later.

Recursive setTimeout guarantees a pause between calls, setInterval - no.

Comment: Sure, that is true. But you're asking a question about updating a timer every second, no mention was made of sliding intervals. In this case, showing a different time every second, using `setInterval` is much clearer in communicating the intentions of your code.